# Union with No_Gaps puts "0" into blank fields using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, union

wanted to overlay two file geodatabase-based featureclasses where one has a smaller extent than the other, but preserve all input features in the output. I used `arcpy.Union_analysis`. In order to maintain feature geometry present in even only one of the two input FCs, I use the "NO_GAPS" option. [The documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000s000000) seems (to me) to state that such features will have the full/combined attributes of both feature classes, but that values will be "blank" (actually says: `This feature will have blank attributes.`)

Problem is that the values for numerical attributes of these features are not actually "NULL" in the output. They are zero.

Is this correct or is there any way to ensure that "NULL" values are produced?

Zero is a legitimate value, so having that in the output is a failure for my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just the way that UNION works.  It works the same on shapefile as on file geodatabase as enterprise geodatabase (and probably coverage, though I didn't test that) whether or not the columns are defined NOT NULL.

It probably wouldn't be a bad idea to contact Tech Support to file a bug and an enhancement request:

Documentation Bug:

- The UNION documentation doesn't explicitly state that all fields will be filled with zero, empty string, and epoch date and it doesn't suggest using a field calculator to update the matching fields as NULL based on -1 fid_*table* column values (there's also something strange happening if a BLOB column is being joined, which might turn out to be a coding defect; they can contact me on that)

Enhancement Request:

- Update UNION processing to support a flag/parameter/environment property to indicate a preference for NULLs in columns that support NULLs (those which are not NOT NULL), instead of zero/blank/epoch.

The workaround is to use the `fid_tablename = -1` test to update the appropriate nullable columns with NULL values (field calculator or similar), or to run with ONLY_FID in the *join_attributes* parameter and OUTER JOIN the source tables' columns based on fid_*tablename*.